# How do I know if an array represents sine wave?

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, trigonometry

I'm working with accelerometer and collecting data for past few seconds. The motion I want to detect can be represented as sine wave in terms of values I'm getting from motion sensor. So to make it sure, I want a way to check if the data returned from sensor do represents a sine wave.

What I want to avoid is to manually compare each value in array and draw a decision.

I'm wondering if there's an efficient way which could tell if my array represents a sine wave or not.

Comment: Are you interested in whether the accelerometer sees any sine wave, or are you looking for one with a specific frequency? Are you looking for a specific phase? How much deviation from an ideal sine wave is permissible, since your data will never be perfect?

Comment: @NeilForrester I'm interested in sine wave. Nothing specific. And sure there will be deviations and I intend to ignore the minor ones. This is something I should determine after demo. Shouldn't I?

Comment: My advice would be to analyze the Fourier Transform of the data (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform). Recognizing a sine wave directly would not be simple, but the Fourier Transform of a pure sine wave is all zeros except for a single non-zero point at the frequency of the sine wave. This would be much easier to recognize. There would, of course, be noise on the sine wave, and so there would be noise in its FT, but the basic pattern of a single big spike would still be there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As commentator @NeilForrester points out, [FFTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) are the way to do this. Writing your own efficient FFT is not easy, but the `Accelerate` framework's [vDSP routines](https://developer.apple.com/reference/accelerate/vdsp) provide a straight-forward way to do it *if you are using Objective-C* - not so straightforward in Swift, due to the use of `UnsafePointer` and `UnsafeMutablePointer` parameters. Here's a simple Swift example of using the FFT.

```
import Foundation
import Accelerate

public struct GFFT {
    let size: Int
    let halfSize: Int
    let log2n: vDSP_Length
    let twoOverSize: [Float]
    var weights: FFTSetup

    init?(size: Int) {
        self.size = size
        self.log2n = vDSP_Length(log2(Float(size)))
        guard let weights = vDSP_create_fftsetup(log2n, FFTRadix(kFFTRadix2)) else {
            print("Aargh in GFFT.fft - weights failed")
            return nil
        }
        self.halfSize = size / 2
        self.twoOverSize = [2 / Float(size)]
        self.weights = weights
    }

    public func forward(realArray: [Float]) -> (magnitude: [Float], phase: [Float]) {
        assert(realArray.count == self.size, "Aargh in GFFT.forward - size mismatch")
        var real = realArray // copy into var
        var imag = GFFT.zeros(size)
        var magnitudesSquared = GFFT.zeros(self.halfSize)
        var magnitudes = GFFT.zeros(self.halfSize)
        var normalizedMagnitudes = GFFT.zeros(self.halfSize)
        var phases = GFFT.zeros(self.halfSize)

        var splitComplex = DSPSplitComplex(realp: &real, imagp: &imag)

        vDSP_fft_zip(self.weights, &splitComplex, 1, self.log2n, FFTDirection(FFT_FORWARD))

        vDSP_zvmags(&splitComplex, 1, &magnitudesSquared, 1, vDSP_Length(self.halfSize))
        vvsqrtf(&magnitudes, &magnitudesSquared, [Int32(self.halfSize)])

        vDSP_zvphas(&splitComplex, 1, &phases, 1, vDSP_Length(self.halfSize))

        vDSP_vsmul(&magnitudes, 1, self.twoOverSize, &normalizedMagnitudes, 1, vDSP_Length(self.halfSize))

        // you may choose to return magnitudesSquared, for the power
        // magnitudes for the scaled amplitudes or 
        // normalizedMagnitudes for, well, normalised magnitude.
        return (normalizedMagnitudes, phases)
    }
    private static func zeros(_ n: Int) -> [Float] { return [Float](repeating: 0, count: n) }
}

let testInput = (0 ..< 512).map {
    return sin(Float($0))
}
if let fft = GFFT(size: testInput.count) {
    let (freq, phase) = fft.forward(realArray: testInput)
    freq.map({$0})
}
```

Playground output:

[image: FFT graph]

As to what you test, it will depend on the actual outputs you get, so I would experiment with what the actual data gives you, but your test should be something like :

- find the mean of the amplitudes
- find the maximum amplitude
- check that the ratio of the two (max / mean) is high
- check that the index of the maximum isn't near zero (or it's likely a DC signal)
- check that any other local maxima (and there will be some) are much smaller than the global maximum.

Comment: Appreciate your effort. However, how do I add the part where given an array, I get a `Bool`, if the array was sine wave.